# how can Sharepoint Person and Group field in custom new form display person name suggestions, after typing first few characters?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-form, people-picker

As with default new form of SharePoint, person and group field allows user to enter multiple names all at once .
Also, my most important concern here is that while typing user name its relevant suggestions automatically show up in drop down. But the same person and group field in custom  new form of SharePoint list doesn't show any name suggestions while typing person name.

Each time user has to type the complete correct name in order for person and group field to accept data.

how can the behavior of custom form's person and group field be changed to act like that of default form. Please guide.
any answers would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is known issue with custom forms.

Can you try replacing

```
"<SharePoint:FormField"
```

with

```
<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker runat="server" ID="MyControlName" 
Required="true"  
ValidationEnabled="true"
InitialHelpText="text"
VisibleSuggestions="3"
Rows="1"
AllowMultipleEntities="true"
CssClass="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" />
```

you can also try the answer suggested in below link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ea38626-8f19-4e75-9d25-6f3eff25f3b5/autocomplete-for-people-picker-field-is-not-working-in-custom-list-form?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: thanks.. i tried your suggestion but after entering person's name in field the value is not saved to list.